# XNA reference error, changed workspace and can't run

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Me and a couple of my friends were on an army network when we wrote the game (XNA 4.0 for VS10 32bit PCs),
and now we got it and it gives some error when we try to run the XNA part.

I try to run the server, whose main consists of Initialization of the server class and the start method.

The program throws a `BadImageTypeException` on the `ctor` of the server class instance initialization.

Since my windows is not in english I can't really give you the exception in gives but I do have a warning that says:

> "Warning 1 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. Game_Of_Throws_Server"

Kinda been waiting for a long time for the game to go WWW and we wanna keep working on it,
but this is a small but annoying problem that keeps us from continuing the development of the game.

Tried removing the assembly reference from the assemblies list and adding it again (The **Microsot.XNA.Framework** reference) but it didn't change a thing. Windows is Win7 64bit, VS is VS13Community version.

If anyone would like to skype or something of that sort to see the problem more clearely, send me a pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get errors like that if the assembly you reference has a different target platform to the assembly referencing it e.g. You have an 'Any CPU' project referencing an 'x86' assembly. Are you certain that the 'Platform target' setting of the project producing this error really is set to x86?

If you're referencing the x86 version of Microsoft.Xna.Framework, you should change the project referencing it to also be x86. If an x64 version of Microsoft.Xna.Framework is also available, you can get creative with your csproj file to ensure the right one is pulled in based on the build you're doing (native Visual Studio support for switching references based on the target platform of the build is not good).